# How to deploy locally already installed artifact with Maven

Tags: maven, maven-3, tycho, maven-deploy-plugin

### Story

I know, that maven deploy command runs through the whole lifecycle. My problem, that it takes to much time in my case. Let me explain:

- There is an application built up from a **Server, and a single sourced Eclipse RAP&RCP** client
- The communication is defined by **shared API projects** which are built together
  with the Server, but also needed by the GUI projects
- The **GUI** projects    are **built by Tycho**, so its impossible to build
  both of them in one    build (in one reactor, **EDIT:** since the P2 artifacts are different for RCP and RAP)
- I build a release with a multi step Jenkins build. To make sure, that
  everything is fine I **first make a clean install** for Server and the
  GUI variations one by one, and **then I deploy** them, if nothing fails

### Question

Building everything twice takes a lot of time. Is there anything like "***please simply deploy all built artifacts*** as they are from my local repository to the POM defined repository **with skipping the whole lifecycle**"?

Comment: It sounds to me that you didn't understand the maven lifecycle, cause if you call **mvn deploy** the install is part of that. So it does not make sense to call first **mvn install** and afterwards **mvn deploy**.

Comment: I added a small edit to make it more clear.

Comment: are you using a repository manager such as Artifactory or Nexus?

Comment: We are using the free version of Nexus.

Comment: See my other question and answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16793217/337621

Answer (score 7):

If you have the artifact already by the previous build, you may consider the [deploy:deploy-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) by following the [Guide to deploying 3rd party JARs to remote repository](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html). I always use this goal to publish some stable artifact to the developer public remote repository for letting other team to test/use.

I hope this may help.

Comment: Looks like if you're trying ACTUALLY deploy the artifacts currently installed in your `.m2/repository` maven complains with an error: ```Cannot deploy artifact from the local repository`` (trying to find a workaround for it)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is a pure Maven solution to this. The problem is that your deploy only build won't know which artifacts to deploy – AFAIK this information is only in the in-memory Maven model and not persisted to the target folder.

The problem can be solved with a Maven repository manager that supports staging, like the (commercial) Nexus Pro. Then, your build would deploy straight away into a staging repository, and only promote the artifacts to the (main) repository if everything succeeded.