# Staged deployment of snapshot artifacts with Maven and Jenkins

Tags: maven, jenkins, snapshot, staging, tycho

### Problem Description

We have several multi-module projects which are depending on each other. So something like this:

- **messaging**
- **framework**
- **othercomponent**

They have separate source control repository, and lets say, that submodules inside **messaging** and **othercomponent** are using bundles from the submodules of **framework**. All of the projects are OSGI based multi-module maven projects. All of them have a server part, and a single sourced GUI part (Eclipse RAP+RCP). So this ends up in a three step maven based build for all of these multi-module projects *(since Tycho builds cannot be mixed with plain old Maven Builds)*:

- Building server part
- Building RAP GUI part
- Building RCP GUI part

And finally there is an *end product* multi-module maven project (lets call it **ourproduct**), which uses **messaging**, **framework** and **othercomponent**. The project **ourproduct** has different version number than the other three, which are having a common version number.

We build the whole thing with Jenkins, and the jobs trigger each other depending on the dependency tree. The company decided to use snapshots to get more direct and fast feedback between the 3 framework project developers and the **ourproduct** developers. This can be a nice idea, however there is a big problem.

If during the building chain something is broken, than the snapshot repository contains snapshots of **messaging**, **framework** and **othercomponent**, which cannot work together. This way the developers of **ourproduct** have to wait for a working snapshot set (otherwise they cannot even compile some time). An other problem is that during the build the set of snapshots are also not consistent.

### Idea

For the **messaging**, **framework** and **othercomponent** there is a definite *end job* in Jenkins. If that finishes, then the set of snapshots must be working, so the **ourproduct** team could use it. **So i would need to COLLECT somehow the snapshots created by the build chain, and deploy them only if the whole build chain was successful.**

- **Is there any existing possibility to do this?**

My idea was to simply change the jobs to make only *install* only and not *deploy*. Then at the end I could look for the built snapshots in the local maven repo, and deploy them by a script.

- There is some Staging Concept for Maven (maybe only with Nexus pro). Does it say anything about snapshots?

Any idea is welcome. However i cannot change the fact of using snapshots. So there is no use in convincing me to use releases and no snapshots.

Comment: Not sure about the deploy part, but the Jenkins [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) may help to collect matching "good" build results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

I have found a nice workaround. Steps to take:

1. The build steps have to deploy to a temp folder instead of the normal target repository using the **altDeploymentRepository** parameter (see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-mojo.html)

   mvn deploy -DaltDeploymentRepository=stagingFolder::default::file:///c:/mytempfolder
2. **Run any number of build steps with this setting**, and the artifacts are collected in the folder. You can even resume the builds without problem. You can overwrite artifacts (i do not recommend it however)
3. You have to run the following command after completing all build steps (see http://mojo.codehaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/copy-mojo.html). This uploads all artifacts which were collected temporarly in the folder:

   mvn org.codehaus.mojo:wagon-maven-plugin:copy -Dwagon.source=file:///c:/mytempfolder -Dwagon.target=http://somerepository.com/repositories/snapshots -Dwagon.targetId=idreferredinsettingsxmltogetauthorization

### Important Note

The wagon goal should be run in a folder, where there is no pom file (so it must be run without project). Otherwise there is a weird error with the **fromDir** parameter.

### Known Limitations

1. The build steps should run using the same local repository, since if
   the steps need the artifacts produced by other artifacts, they can
   find it in the local repository.
2. This solution does not read the POM to get the repository to which the artifacts should be uploaded. This is wired today into the wagon command. But I can live with it now :)

Comment: You don't need to share the same local Maven repository if you add the file repository you deployed to as `repository`, e.g. via the `settings.xml`.

Comment: Yeah, but it can happen, that you want to do the whole thing with dynamic temp folder name, and in this case editing the settings.xml on the fly is pain in the ass.

Answer (score 1):

Jenkins allows to collect artifacts of other builds (if they mark these in their project configuration).
Your integration tests could use that construct to collect required from the snapshots builds and only upload a set of bundles to Nexus once integration tests are completed. You might start by inspecting the manifests from the OSGI bundles.I suggest to use jar-signing as a staging-marker, because it is easy in forensic analysis by devops.

btw Nexus Pro has a staging concept.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Right now I am completely happy with my solution ;)